# Issue when deploying nodejs in Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, node-modules

Until yesterday, i was able to deploy successfully nodejs application to Amazon EC2 but today it is failing, i looked over the eb-engine logs and I am guessing it is not able to download phantomjs dependency. But i am not quite sure but may be node-cron doing it. Also I am not sure which library is internally installing that.
Attaching the eb-engine log as well as package.json
[eb-engine.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1imvO8d9vqouokEOJUPNBR89XWjIOgopw/view?usp=sharing)

Package.json is below:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-jwt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 14.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prod:start": "pm2-runtime app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "address": "^1.1.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.787.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "easyinvoice": "^2.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.1.10",
    "geolocation": "^0.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^59.0.0",
    "internal-ip": "^7.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.16",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "nodemailer-express-handlebars": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "oauth2orize-jwt-bearer": "^0.2.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-oauth2-jwt-bearer": "^0.2.0",
    "pdf-creator-node": "^2.3.4",
    "peer": "^0.6.1",
    "plivo": "^4.12.0",
    "pm2": "^5.1.2",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "razorpay": "^2.0.6",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^4.3.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",
    "unirest": "^0.6.0",
    "yamljs": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried npm install before npm run?

Comment: Where do you want me to try that and how will that help resolve this issue? Can you explain if you understand this issue?

Comment: It's run in the Amazon EC2 automatically during deployment is what I believe

Comment: Just go inside a project and run `npm i` in the terminal.

Comment: Share the logs if it fails.